# Is there a command so that when something is 3 less than or 3 more than the answer it would do something?

Tags: python, random, numbers, generator

I am making a random number guessing game and I was wondering if when your guess is 3 less than or more than the answer it would print something like "Close! The answer was (the answer)"

```
import random
while True:
    dicesize = raw_input('What size die do you want to guess from?>')
    number = random.randrange(1, int(dicesize))
    guess = raw_input('What is your guess?>')
    if int(guess) == number:
        print 'Correct!'
        print " "
        # less than 3 print "close"?
        # more than 3 print "close"?
    else:
        print 'Nope! The answer was', number
        print " "
```

(I have the print " " to make a space between each of the loops)

Comment: You can just use `if -3 < (number-guess) < 3`. Or `if abs(number-guess) < 3` to say "under 3 less or more". Or just translate the English almost straight to Python: `if guess < answer-3 or guess > answer+3` to say "if your guess is 3 less or your guess is 3 more".

Answer (score 5):

```
while True:
    dicesize = raw_input('What size die do you want to guess from?>')
    number = random.randrange(1, int(dicesize))
    guess = int(raw_input('What is your guess?>'))
    if guess == number:
        print('Correct!')
        print(" ")
    elif abs(number-guess) < 3:
        print("Close")
    else:
        print('Nope! The answer was', number)
```

Just get  the  [absolute value](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#abs) `abs(number-guess)`, which will cover both cases, if the guess is less than 3 above or  below the number.

```
In [1]: abs(10-7)
Out[1]: 3

In [2]: abs(7-10)
Out[2]: 3
```

Answer (score 2):

More simply, use chained conditionals

```
if number-3 < guess < number+3:
    print("Close")
```